# Como instalo de manera adecuada NetBeans IDE 8.2, ya que no permite el acceso para trabajra JAVA

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no permite la descarga en su totalidad

me ayudan por favor

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberías instalar JRE y JDK correctamente en su versión mas actual y que estas sean la misma versión, para posteriormente instalar el NetBeans 8.2, recuerda que al abrirlo debes de esperar a que se instalen todos los complementos, pero para ello en tu imagen no se muestra el `java aplication` por lo cual puede ser un problema con el JDK, pero en principio al instalar correctamente JDK y JRE el IDE se instalara correctamente y solo es cuestión de descargar los complementos.
Pero puedes optar por una versión mas reciente ya que 8.2 de NetBeans ya quedo obsoleta en su totalidad y ya no aparece en la pagina oficial.